# RegisterUser() Dwolla API method and user phone number

Tags: validation, dwolla

I can't figure out why I can use `RegisterUser()` on my site only to have to re-enter some of the information when I go to Dwolla.com. I think it has to do with not entering a valid phone number when using `RegisterUser()` but I didn't get any errors when entering a valid vs. invalid phone number on my site.

This gets at a larger question: What Dwolla API methods validate vs. fail validation when a Dwolla user doesn't have a phone number? Currently the phone number requirement seems inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

You're absolutely right, Tim.  In its current state, the Register User method is, to be honest, limited in its usefulness.  You pass data about a new user and have it created, but when the user logs in, they have to re-enter much of that same information (regardless if they fail phone number validation) which undermines the benefit of registering via the API as opposed to having users make accounts themselves.

We realize this, so we're currently revamping and extending the Register API to give developers more control over the registration process.  We'll be rolling out this update soon, so keep an eye out for it!